# How to listen to a physical button press in windows

Tags: windows

My laptop has two extra physical buttons. One of them turns airplane mode on and off the other one just opens a software. I never use these buttons.

So is there a way I could assign them other actions like turn wifi on and off or mute and unmute ?

Comment: not sure it's a question that belongs in this site, but you should read this: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/

Comment: In my case sharpkeys doesn't work because the keys I want to manipulate are not a part of the keyboard nor they are in the standart set of keys. It's the manufacterers addition and keys work before the os loads they are set in bios I guess